# PHP 7.1.33 in MAMP Pro doesn't go above 30 seconds in max_execution_time setting

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm working in a Cake PHP 2 application, I'm running some big queries that require PHP's `max_execution_time` setting to be higher than 30 seconds. I've dumped `phpinfo()` on the page and can see that it's being pulled through, and if I change it from 40 to something like 5, it does exit after 5 seconds.

But anything above 30 seconds and it just exits at 30. What am I missing?

I've tried editing every PHP conf file offered by MAMP pro and still no luck.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I never used CakePHP, but since that value can be changed during runtime, make sure that CakePHP doesn't change it in somewhere. If that is the case, then you wouldn't see it it in phpinfo() unless you call phpinfo() through some route in CakePHP.

Comment: If using php-fpm,  set the execution time in the pool config AND make certain that the Timeout and ProxyTimeout  apache settings  are sufficient, typically in vhost files.